# Chaining a similar promise ambiguity in Protractor

Tags: promise, protractor

I am using EXCELJS to read data from Excel file . Created a function,**allinExcel** which returns the column values in promise . As I need 2 columns , I have chained the similar promise functions - **allinExcel** . In this context , yet times , I get the expected results and yet times I don't ,which is ambiguous . The ProExcel file consists of 2 columns  .The expected result from the below code is 2 arrays which includes each of the column contents . Any help in this is very much useful.
The expected result is `[ <1 empty item>, 'GEL', 'BEL', 'HEL', 'SEL' ] [ <1 empty item>, 55, 555, 66, 666 ]`
But if I get a column value using a single promise , I get the result every time without any ambiguity .

```
describe("Excel Read ",function(){
   function allinExcel(colNum){
    var Excel = require('exceljs');
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    var excelFilePath  = "ExcelData/ProExcel.xlsx"
    return workbook.xlsx.readFile(excelFilePath).then(function() {
      var worksheet=workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
      return worksheet.getColumn(colNum+1).values
    },function(error){
      console.log(error)
       return fail
    })
  }
it("Excel Operation",function(){
    allinExcel(0).then(function(col0){
      allinExcel(1).then(function(col1){
        console.log(col1,col0)

      })

    })
})
```

The following is the conf.js file

```
// conf.js

var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  getPageTimeout:20000, // browser.get timeout
  allScriptsTimeout: 360000, // Time to load the DOM
  jasmineNodeOpts: {defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000}, //For individual it
  framework: 'jasmine',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',

    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--start-maximized','disable-infobars'//,'--headless'
      ]
    }
  },

onPrepare: function() {
  global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
      savePath: 'target/reports',
      screenshotsFolder: 'images',
      takeScreenshots: true,
      takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
      fixedScreenshotName: false,
      fileName: 'currentRun',
      cleanDestination: true
    })
  );

},
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
},

specs: ['specs/WebTables.js'],

};
```

Comment: I can get correct result each time even I put calling the `allinExcel` promise chain in a for loop. I used `exceljs@1.6.3`.  Please try latest exceljs and another new excel file.

Comment: @yong , even I am using the same exceljs version . Thanks , for loop works for me as well which would be one of the solutions for my issue . I am more keen to know why the chain of promises is not working in my case .

Answer (score 0):

Please try your function and code in a javascript file without using protractor to see your code can work well or not.

1. Create a temp folder
2. New a file with name: `test.js in the temp folder`, and copy following code into the file.
3. Copy the excel `ProExcel.xlsx` into the temp folder
4. Open an cmd window and enter the temp folder
5. Run `node test.js` in cmd window

   ```
   // test.js 
   function allinExcel(colNum) {
       var Excel = require('exceljs');
       var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
       var excelFilePath = "ProExcel.xlsx"
       return workbook.xlsx.readFile(excelFilePath).then(function () {
           var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
           return worksheet.getColumn(colNum + 1).values
       }, function (error) {
           console.log(error)
           return fail
       })
   }


   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].forEach(function (it, index) {

       allinExcel(0).then(function (col0) {
           allinExcel(1).then(function (col1) {

               console.log('\n#### ' + index)
               console.log(col0, col1)

           })
       })

   })
   ```

If you can't get same result in each loop, change your nodejs version(I used v10.9.0).

If you can get same result in each loop, the problem comes from Protractor side.

Add `return` for each nested function for `then()`, run again.

```
it("Excel Operation",function(){
    allinExcel(0).then(function(col0){
      return allinExcel(1).then(function(col1){
        return console.log(col1,col0)

      })

    })
})
```

Comment: yes it is working fine for me using node . Does it mean it is an issue from Protractor or specifically from EXCELJS . My node version in v11.4.0

Comment: Did you set `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,` in your protractor conf.js? Please show your protractor conf.js in your question.

Comment: I didn't set SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER to any value which means  it is true by default if I am not wrong .Posted my conf.js in the main question . Thank you :)

Comment: Add `return` before `allinExcel(1).then(...)` and try again.

Comment: The ambiguity of the output is still continuing . I mean some times the codes returns me the results , some it dont .